# Is it possible to redirect each url request to index.html or stop redirection to any html page or html files only with pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I using a live server (VS code extension) to work on my site and I have only one html file (index.html) because i trying to create something like SPA without frameworks as I will change dynamically the html content to simulate that they are different pages.

When entered url - example : http://localhost:5000/templates

I'm getting an error 404 (Not Found) I don`t want to redirect me to other html files.

The questions are:

1 ) It`s is possible to do without (.htaccess ) file?

2 ) It`s is possible change url pathname without redirect nowhere.

3 ) It`s is possible to redirect each url request аlways to index.html using only pure JS.

Comment: js cannot handle your situation either you need server script to route all to html file or nginx conf or htacees for apache server

Comment: server side only